# Move section to new file in vim

Tags: vim

I have a `section` in `file1` which should be moved to `file2`. Normally I'd do this by visually-selecting the block, deleting it, `:wq` from `file1`, open `file2`, then paste.

Is there an easy way to move a block of text from `file` to `file2` without closing `vim`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could open your new file in a split using `:sp newfile` and then delete the block as normal from your first file. Then, change to the other split with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>w</kbd>. Then use `p` to put the deleted content into the other file.

Answer (score 27):

Alternatively:

1. write selection to new file`:'<,'>w file2`
2. then reselect and delete with `gvd`

The first step is covered in *vimtutor* `Lesson 5.3: SELECTING TEXT TO WRITE`.

Comment: Great answer. I think this should be the one marked correct.

Comment: Alternatively to append to a file use `:'<,'>!cat >> other_file`

Answer (score 4):

You could open the file in a new buffer.

just open the file via `:e file2` and paste the text. To move quickly between the buffers use either `:e #` or `:b #`

see `:help buffers` for more information

Answer (score 4):

Since no one mentioned that: you can use tabs instead.

1. Select your block.
2. Delete it with `d`
3. Create a new buffer in new tab with `:tabnew newfile.name`
4. Paste it and save it with `p` and `:w`
5. You can go back with `gT` or close current tab with `:q`

I personally newer use buffers -- only tabs. Read more about them in `:help tabpage`